# Image from Google Sheet not pulling through in Google Slides

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

I'm using Google Sheets to convert a URL to an image and you can see in the 1st screenshot, but when I copy the table (linked) into Google Slides the image doesn't pull through, as you can see in the 2nd screenshot.

Are we able to fix this?

[image: Google Sheets image being created with the 'IMAGE=' formula]

[image: Images cells are blank once copy/pasted into Google Slides]